# C++ linked list weird outputs

Tags: c++, linked-list

So i've been trying to code a linked list. When i debug or if i put one more print statement like this;

```
intlist.add_node(7);
intlist.print_list();
intlist.add_node(8);
```

It works fine prints;

```
5
7
5
7
8
```

But if i remove that statement, it only prints three eights. Same goes for debugging, it seems working but if i just run it doesn't. I didn't understand what is wrong.
Here's my main;

```
int main(){
  Linked_list intlist;
  intlist.add_node(5);
  intlist.add_node(7);
  intlist.print_list();
  intlist.add_node(8);
  intlist.print_list();
  return 0;
}
```

header;

```
class Linked_list{
public:
  Linked_list();

  void add_node(int data);
  void remove_node(int data);
  int get_data(int index);
  void print_list();

  struct Node {
      int data;
      Node* next;
  };

  Node* head;
  int lenght;
};
```

And header's source file;

```
Linked_list::Linked_list(){
  head = 0;
  lenght = 0;
}

void Linked_list::add_node(int data){
  Node* newnode = new Node;
  newnode->data = data;
  newnode->next = NULL;
  if (head == 0) {head = newnode; lenght = 1; return;}
  else{
      Node* temp = new Node;
      temp = head;
      while (temp->next != NULL){
          temp = temp->next;

      }
      lenght++;
      temp->next = newnode;
      delete temp;
  }
}


void Linked_list::remove_node(int data){
    return;
}

int Linked_list::get_data(int index){
    return 0;
}

void Linked_list::print_list(){
    if (head == 0) {std::cout << "List is empty!!" << std::endl; 
    return;}
    else{
        Node* ptr = new Node;
        ptr = head;
        for (int i = lenght; i > 0; i--){
            std::cout << ptr->data << std::endl;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a bug in your print_list. Why are you allocating a node then leaking the allocated memory on the next statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your add_node function should be:

```
void Linked_list::add_node(int data) {

  Node* newnode = new Node;
  newnode->data = data;
  newnode->next = NULL;

  if (head == 0) {
      head = newnode;
      lenght = 1;
      return;
  } else {
      //Node* temp = new Node;
      Node *temp = head;
      while (temp->next != NULL) {
          temp = temp->next;
      }

      lenght++;
      temp->next = newnode;
      //delete temp;
  }
}
```

You don't need to create a new `Node` object since you are only looking to reference head. `delete temp` actually deletes the content of the address previously pointed to by `temp`, which is the last element of your list.

Comment: It's good to remove that memory leak but that doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get it then, but this deletion definitely breaks the printing since the data for the deleted Node is no longer accessible.

Comment: The second commented out line was the real culprit :) Didn't see that the first time.